# Can I download my completed project file in github, put the folder inside sublime text, cd to it, and run rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Guys this is just a worst case scenario.

For example, I have a project named project-x that is already done and it's pushed on github. What if I have to update some codes but my computer suddenly won't work anymore, so I buy a new computer, installed all what is needed like sublime text, ruby, rails, git, etc. Can I just "download as zip" my project-x from github, put the project-x folder to sublime text, cd into it, and run rails server without any problems? Can I still push my changes to github?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to do `git clone https://github.com/your_name/your_project.git` on the command line and then change local files as you wish.

Edit: The method above is preferred over downloading a zip since you can diff the changes etc. If you still wish to download a zip you can call this URL in your browser or curl/wget: `https://github.com/your_name/your_project/archive/master.zip`